# CUDA C++ Linking error undefined reference threadIdx.x and blockDim.x

Tags: c++, cuda

I am trying to compile my code using CUDA for OpenGL application. 
here is my code.

```
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda_gl_interop.h>
#include <device_launch_parameters.h>

float t = 0.0f;   //timer
float3* device;   //pointer to memory on the device (GPU VRAM)
GLuint buffer;   //buffer

__global__ void demo(int * d_a)
{
    int a=blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
}
```

I got an error

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/MatchSlide.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `demo(void*)':
main.cpp:33: undefined reference to `blockDim'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:33: undefined reference to `blockIdx'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:33: undefined reference to `threadIdx'
```

also in CMakeFile, I defined

```
# Look for Truetype && libpng
find_package(Freetype REQUIRED)
include_directories(${FREETYPE_INCLUDE_DIRS})

pkg_check_modules(PNG REQUIRED libpng)
include_directories(${PNG_INCLUDE_DIRS})
find_package(CUDA  REQUIRED)
include_directories("${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++14 -Wall -lcurand -lglfw -lGLEW -lGLU -lGL -lglut -lfreetype -lpng -lpthread -lX11  -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcudart  -lcuda")
```

```
/**
 * User:Demo
 * Date: 30/4/20.
 * Sample Project
 */

// Headers

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "Event.h"
#include "ResourceManager.h"
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda_gl_interop.h>
#include <device_launch_parameters.h>

float t = 0.0f;   //timer
float3* device;   //pointer to memory on the device (GPU VRAM)
GLuint buffer;   //buffer


__global__ void rendering(float3 *output,float k)
{
    int a=blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
}
```

as you can see in my code, I am trying to define just a simple thread function to run my code. But it is generating errors that help me out where am I making mistakes in defining Cuda in my application.

Comment: Please paste your cmake file as well.

Comment: That clearly isn't the code -- the error is occurring on line 33 of main.cpp, and you have posted 12 lines of code.

Comment: Change your file's name from `main.cpp` to `main.cu` and see if it solves the issue.

Comment: @RealReza the project is in c++ so it can be possible to run Cuda in simple CPP file project.

Comment: @Bruce: No. If you put CUDA code in a .cpp file, the composition will fail. The file must have a .cu extension

Answer (score 1):

Please read [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#supported-input-file-suffixes) on the supported file extensions by nvcc. If your source file includes both host code and device functions, it is no longer a mere C++ source file. Three solutions I can think of:

1- Change `main.cpp` to `main.cu`. But if you really don't want to change `main.cpp` to `main.cu` (not sure why), then consider these two options:

2- Include your kernel `demo` in a secondary file with extension `cu`,

3- Compile your `.cpp` file as is with option `x cu`, like:

```
nvcc main.cpp -x cu
```

by which you are forcing the compiler to treat your `main.cpp` file as a CUDA source file even though the extension is `cpp`.

Comment: Make senes to me. I think i found my answer. thanks for the tips